# SPDocumentLibrary.CheckedOutFiles does not return all files

Tags: document-library, object-model

I am working through some code samples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdocumentlibrary.checkedoutfiles.aspx) that is suppose to return Checked Out files but my tests is showing a problem.

Here you can see that both "default" and "foo" in my Page library are checked out yet only "foo" is returned when I call IList files = library.CheckedOutFiles;

Is there something unique about "default" that makes it not return?

Thanks for reading.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `SPDocumentLibrary.CheckedOutFiles` returns the ****new****ly uploaded files that are checked out. (notice the **new** near the foo document).

From MSDN:

> When someone creates a **new** file or adds a **new** file to a library that
>   requires check-out...

So when using `SPDocumentLibrary.CheckedOutFiles` you will not have all checked out files.

You can have more information on this subject and on how to get all checked out files from [here](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/154).

Comment: To take this one step further I believe its not just "new" documents. I believe it to be any documents that have no checked in version.